# open a window(wpf) on the foreground from a page(wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working at a `WPF` desktop application, in this application I open a wpf page which contains a listbox of contacts on a frame.

When I double-click on a contact, a window opens to modify it. The problem is that the window is opened in the back and I want it on the foreground , I used this code

```
private void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
   {
       modify_contact window = new modify_contact(list[listBox.SelectedIndex]);
       window.Owner=this;
       window.Show();
    }
}
```

It didn't work because it's and not a window 
So what can I do to make my opened on the foreground ?

Comment: "It didn't work because it's and not a window". Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
    { 
        modify_contact window = new modify_contact(list[listBox.SelectedIndex]);
        window.Owner = MainWindow.GetWindow(this);
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a `Window` and set it's `Content` like this

```
private void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   modify_contact window = new modify_contact(list[listBox.SelectedIndex]);
   Window windowHost = new Window
   {
      Title = "I'm the title",
      Content = window
   };
   windowHost.ShowDialog();
}
```